# How do I obtain the full path of an isolated storage file

Tags: isolatedstorage

How do I obtain the fully qualified path of an isolated storage file for a WPF application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use reflection to do so, as shown in the [linked](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/23ec13d5-6013-4974-b150-649f36d884d0/) forum post:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream oStream =
    new IsolatedStorageFileStream(ISOLATED_FILE_NAME, FileMode.Create, isoStore);

// Get the physical path using reflection

String filePath = oStream.GetType().GetField("m_FullPath",
     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(oStream).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(filePath);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to obtain the path using a Win32 call via the low-level handle?

Comment: @Bob - you could probably `PInvoke` something like that, but I assumed you would be using managed code.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 Mobile the isolated-storage-path is equal to `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`.

If you know the relative file-path inside the isolated-storage you can use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to create the full path.

You can use `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().GetFileNames()` to list all files in the isolated-storage.